# Traffic court processing time

Tags: traffic, alabama

I received 2 tickets nearly 13 years ago in Alabama. I went to prison on unrelated charges. I just got out, I tried to get my driver license, found out they are suspended because of the tickets. I contacted the court and they can not find any records or information regarding the tickets. I can't pay the reinstatement fee until the tickets are paid, is there time limit the court has to find the tickets?

Comment: What state/country? And did you mean "I am *not* out", or "I am *now* out"? Cause the former doesn't make much sense; inmates don't need drivers' licenses.

Comment: Alabama/USA and I just got out of prison

Comment: Assuming the arresting officer was state or local police (as opposed to, say, a sheriff's deputy)...have you contacted the police for info on the ticket? They should provide enough info to help the courts find the case. (And if they don't have it, then frankly, i'd get a lawyer to make the government prove the ticket even existed.)